# Let site administrator manage default values in Django

Tags: python, django

I need to let the site administrator set few defaults, without embedding them to `settings.py`.

For example the admin sets some value, that will be default in some models for 3 months, after that admin changes it to another.

How to implement it nicely in Django, those defaults being able to be used in other models ?

Comment: You can use functions to set default values in your models, so you can fetch values from your database there.

Comment: Agree, also there are applications that will handle some routine tasks for you. Like django-dbsettings - you'll setup what settings you want and then it'll give you admin interface to modify them. But that app seems outdated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [django-livesettings](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-livesettings/1.4-3), which is used in [satchmo project](http://www.satchmoproject.com/).